# Exception handling trigger is causing error ORA-06512: error during execution of trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I know similar questions have been asked, but none of the solutions I have viewed have helped me on this question. The statement bellow successfully throws the error and I see the message when a number out of the range is entered, but It also creates an error. If there is no error needed, no error is thrown.
The errors are as follow:

> ORA-20000: Cost cannot be negative or greater than $1000.
> ORA-06512: at "TEST.VERCOST", line 2
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST.VERCOST'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VerCost
    BEFORE 
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF cost ON items
    FOR EACH ROW ENABLE
    WHEN (new.cost < 0  OR new.cost > 1000)
BEGIN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Cost cannot be negative or greater than $1000.');
END;

UPDATE items
SET cost = -90
WHERE item = 'Test Item';
```

SQL Logic:
Table items hold various items. I want a trigger if the price is out of a set range.
I test this using an update for a test item known as Test Item.
I am using a WHEN clause rather than a IF/Else statment inside the Pl/sql statment, I tried the If else and got the same error.

I think the error might have to do with some issue with not returning on update but I am not sure.

I know triggers are not ideal, but for the requirements I need to use them here.

Comment: It seems to be working as designed. ORA-04088 means the trigger failed, your custom ORA-20000 explains why.

Comment: + it's much better to use `check` constrains here

Comment: What is the behaviour you are expecting ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie Ideally, the trigger would not fail if the application error is raised, but I see how it fails, just not sure how to approach it in that way.

Comment: What is the frontend to this data ? You could solve it entirely at the front end - either create a validation so the update is not executed if (new.cost < 0  OR new.cost > 1000) or trap the exception raised by the trigger so the end user doesn't get the error.

Comment: @KoenLostrie For sure, this is a practice from textbook for an upcoming midterm. There was no solution given. The prof said triggers will be on the midterm but not a ton of material was given so I am looking to understand triggering errors as that was what was mainly covered.

Comment: @In that case this is expected behaviour :). In our apps we use triggers to avoid connect by loops in hierarchical data - similar to your example.

Comment: @James_B *"Ideally, the trigger would not fail if the application error is raised"* Triggers can only succeed or fail. If they succeed, there's no error message. If they fail, there's no avoiding the "trigger failed" error.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes thankyou for that up for me. My code was correct for what I was looking to do, just was not sure of it.